# Why amazon s3 cli copy much faster than java sdk in the same bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I have a file in s3 bucket say like `s3://prefix/file1` with size 2G
I tried to copy it to `s3://prefix/file2`

The CLI I used is `aws s3 cp s3://prefix/file1 s3://prefix/file2`

The sdk usage is `amazonS3.copyObject("prefix","file1","prefix", "file2")`

CLI method took ~15s while sdk method took ~30s.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the TransferManager, like in this "old" blog post of AWS:
https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/developer/using-transfer-manager-to-copy-amazon-s3-objects/

I'm not very familiar with JAVA programming, but in several applications I've been involved in migrating/optimizing, switching from the "normal" SDK methods to operations using TransferManager with Java has sometimes helped improve performance.

Maybe this could also improve the performance for you.

Comment: I use TranferManger for the upload but it can't be used for copying within buckets